# order list is not displayed on order_list.html?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

order history is not displayed on orders_list.html file.
**order_list.html**

```
{% if order_details %}
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for order in order_details %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order.created|date:"d M Y" }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order.total }}</td>
                        <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                        <td><a href="">View Order</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% else %}
        <p>
            You have not placed any orders yet.
            <br><br>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Continue shopping</a>
        </p>
    {% endif %}
```

**views.py file**

```
def orderHistory(request):
    global order_details
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        email = str(request.user.email)
        order_details = Order.objects.filter(emailAddress=email)

    return render(request, 'orders_list.html', {'order_details': order_details})
```

**the result to above is**

ORDER HISTORY

You have not placed any orders yet.

Continue shopping

this shows that the if statement always returns false while there are rows of orders in order table.

i expect the result to be the list of orders placed from the account.

Comment: Why dont you add some debugging in your views code to print the order_details to see exactly what is being passed back to the html

Comment: Also why is order_details a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time this has something to do with

```py
order_details = Order.objects.filter(emailAddress=email)
```

You have to check if this queryset returns any value at all. Because when you use filter if queryset is empty you won't get any error and this may be the reason why you can't display anything.

However, you will need to use some simple print statements in your view to check the queryset.

If the queryset has values then try adding

```py
return render(request, 
              'orders_list.html',
              {'order_details': Order.objects.filter(emailAddress=email)})
```

as a last try.